# jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-3

jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated in jquery 3.X.X? 
I'm making a mess with documentation.

mycode is:
`$("#myDiv").load('mypage.html');`

How I can load mypage.html into #myDiv?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code is correct. This [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you use isn't deprecated, but the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is.

Answer (score 2):

From [Beamtic's website](https://beamtic.com/fn-load-is-deprecated-wordpress)

You can try replacing the `load()` method with `on('load', ...)`

Given deprecated code:

```
tjq(this).load(function() {
  tjq(this).closest(".middle-block").middleblock();
});
```

Try changing it to:

```
tjq(this).on('load', function() {
  tjq(this).closest(".middle-block").middleblock();
});
```

Jacob's webpage linked to at the top of this post also gives solutions to other similar deprecated jQuery code.

That said, since you are passing in a URL, not a function, I am not sure how that would translate to your case. I mean I guess `$("#myDiv")` is a function?).

To be sure, many people (including myself before now) are looking for the solution shown above. I am just not sure *exactly* how to translate your code to work for you.