# fn.load is deprecated

Tags: jquery, deprecation-warning

Is there any way to avoid below warning by jQuery?

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

My code is given below:

```
var url = '../Order/GetOrderDetails' 
$("#divOrder").load(url);
```

Note: I am using jQuery 2.2.0 version

Comment: My [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68219199/5411817) may or may not help some people reading this post, though it addresses a slightly different deprecation warning (*jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated*). And here is the webpage that helped address the issue I was looking for: https://beamtic.com/fn-load-is-deprecated-wordpress. It addresses the jQuery deprecation of `fn.load()` with favor to `on('load', fn)` and similar deprecations.

Comment: These similar looking questions have several solutions you can look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest AND https://stackoverflow.com/q/28322636/5411817

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$.ajax()`. It looks like `$.load()` uses synchronous AJAX, which freezes the browser's main thread while the server is preparing and returning a response. As the warning says, that's horrible for user experience.

Comment: Isn't `.load()` a [short-hand method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for `.ajax()`?

Comment: I tried $.ajax and in success i assigned data in to div using .html(). Then it says fn.html is deprecated.

Comment: `$.html` is dangerous because is exposes you to XSS vulnerabilities. You'll want to use `$.text`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález apparently it's synchronous in `2.2.0`

Comment: Ah... I really hate documentation that doesn't take versions into account :(

Comment: I made the changes as given below before the ajax call and now warning got removed. $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, original_Options, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322636/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-warning-and-script/28323156#28323156